# how to make auto adjustable controls?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, winapi

As we dynamically add controls to a web page, its location is automatically adjusted, one control will not place over another. 
Can we do the same in windows Form Application.
  I have to add dynamic label, textbox and buttons at last of an **existing** win form.

Comment: You can use FlowLayoutPanel Control and create dynamic control in it. It will automatically adjust the location of the control.

Comment: Yes i got it. This is really a good control. I can set margins to reduce the distance between the margins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) control.

> Represents a panel that dynamically lays out its contents horizontally or vertically.

When you drop controls on the `FlowLayoutPanel`, it will take care of automatically spacing one from another. If you dock it to the form, such that it resizes with the form, then it will also handle moving controls to the next row / column as needed, so they don't become hidden beyond the boundaries of the form.

[image]

If you want to group some controls together, place them inside a `Panel` and then use that inside the `FlowLayoutPanel`. Here's some code to demonstrate:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var panel = new Panel { BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle, Width = 100, BackColor = Color.LightBlue };

    panel.Controls.AddRange(
        new Control[]
    {
        new Label { Text = "Title", Location = new Point(0, 0) },
        new Label { Text = "Subtitle", Location = new Point(0, 25) }
    });

    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to Show Label And Textbox Simultaneously? As in Registration Form, But Dynamically?

Comment: But i have to create dynamic panel and its again very annoying to set position of label and textbox in panel. 
 Could you please send me the code for the same? Thanks in Advance...

Comment: How Can I Decrease the Space Between the Controls in FlowLayoutPanel ??